# How to emulate MATLAB's lsqlin in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, least-squares

my question is simple, is there an easy way to implement `lsqlin` of MATLAB in python? Because, according to the documentation:

> `lsqlin` Constrained linear least squares.
> X = lsqlin(C,d,A,b) attempts to solve the least-squares problem
> min  0.5*(NORM(C*x-d)).^2       subject to    A*x <= b
> x
> where C is m-by-n.

in scipy there is `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` but, looking at the documentation, it solves:

> minimize 0.5 * ||A x - b||**2
> subject to lb <= x <= ub

So I could use it just by setting, as upper bound, x<=BA^-1 and -inf as lower bound but this can't be the final solution (what if the inverse doesn't exist?). What could I use?

Comment: What MATLAB is doing is not simple, so your question isn't simpler either.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. I used cvxpy library (https://www.cvxpy.org/). It's easy defining a least squares problem with this kind of constraint. The resolution of the output is not equal (in MATLAB there is 2.3e-16 while in python it returns 0) but I think that it can be a good approximation. If I find how to increase resulution I will update the answer.

Comment: I would not be too picky about the difference between 1e-16 and 0. This is all within numerical tolerance for zero, and if you have a model where the 1e-16 in a solution is really meaningful then you should very, very seriously rethink that model. Also, a funny thing is that 99.9999% of the people making similar observations want it exactly the other way around ;). You can never expect two different numerical algorithms for the same optimization problem to give 100% identical answers since the computations are done in finite precision.